# Returning data to a partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a blog that has a sidebar with a partial view in it that enables users to sign up for my e-mail newsfeed. What I'm trying to do is returning the user to the page they came from after posting some data, and displaying any validation or return messages in the form's partial view.

The problem is that my partial view opens in a new window (without the lay-out). How can I fix this so it returns to my blog, with the return data in de sidebar?

This is my view:

```
@using Blog.Models.Entities
@model Subscriber

<header>
    <h2>Subscribe</h2>
</header>

<p>Subscribe to my e-mail newsfeed.</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Subscription"))
{
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)</div>
    <div class="editor-field ">@Html.EditorFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)</div>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />

    <p>@ViewBag.Result</p>
}
```

And the relevant pieces of controller that are processing the data:

```
public ActionResult Form()
{
    return PartialView("_Form");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(Subscriber subscriber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Subscriber foundSubscriber = _repository.Subscribers.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(subscriber.Email)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (foundSubscriber != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This e-mail address has already been added.");
            return PartialView("_Form", subscriber);
        }

        _repository.SaveSubscriber(subscriber);

        ViewBag.Result = "Succesfully subscribed to the newsletter.";
        return PartialView("_Form");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please provide a valid e-mail address.");
    return PartialView("_Form", subscriber);
}
```

Comment: Where is this opening in a new window? Theres no code shown that links to your partial.

Comment: I see I made a little mistake, but when I use "return PartialView" the partial view is rendered without the lay-out instead of in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem. I implemented it with AJAX and ended up with the following code:

_Index.cshtml

```
<header>
    <h2>Subscribe</h2>
</header>

<p>Subscribe to my e-mail newsfeed.</p>

<div id="subscription-form">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_Form");}
</div>
```

_Form.cshtml

```
@using Blog.Models.Entities
@model Subscriber
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        LoadingElementId = "loading",
        LoadingElementDuration = 2000,
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "subscription-form"
    };
}

<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <p>Processing request...</p>
</div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Subscription", ajaxOptions))
{
    <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)</div>
    <div class="editor-field ">@Html.EditorFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)</div>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(subscriber => subscriber.Email)

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
}
```

_Succes.cshtml

```
@using Blog.Models.Entities
@model Subscriber

<p id="subscription-result">@ViewBag.Result</p>
```

And the following controller action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return PartialView("_Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Index(Subscriber subscriber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Subscriber foundSubscriber = _repository.Subscribers.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(subscriber.Email)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (foundSubscriber != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This e-mail address has already been added.");
            return PartialView("_Form", subscriber);
        }

        _repository.SaveSubscriber(subscriber);

        ViewBag.Result = "Succesfully subscribed to the newsletter.";
        return PartialView("_Succes", subscriber);
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please provide a valid e-mail address.");
    return PartialView("_Form", subscriber);
}
```

I hope this will help anyone trying to achieve the same in the future. BTW, I found the solution on this blog: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/using-unobtrusive-ajax-forms-in-asp-net-mvc3/.

Answer (score 1):

When submitting a form, the browser sends an HTTP Post request to the server.  The browser then displays the Response's payload.  Your post Controller Action is returning a PartialView, which the browser is happily rendering (even though it doesn't have the html, head, or body tags necessary to make it truly valid HTML).

It sounds like you want the browser to keep most of your page loaded and rendered, post the form, then take the resulting HTML and only replace a portion of the loaded page.  Simply put, the browser isn't smart enough to do that.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

- User fills in some form data and clicks save/submit/go/whatever.
- However, you don't want the browser to submit the form, because it won't preserve most of the current page the way you want.
- Instead, you want the "submit" button to call some local javascript.
- That local JS should bundle up the user-entered form data, craft a POST with that data as the payload, and submit the POST using Ajax.  This will keep the current page loaded, while the ajax request hits your Controller Action
- You controller action stays the way it is, and returns a partial view.
- Your JS function that launched the Ajax call must also define a "success" function which will get called when the operation completes.
- Within that success function, your javascript will grab the HTML from the response, and use it to replace the area of the page that held the original form.

I highly recommend jQuery - it will make it MUCH easier to craft the Ajax request, handle the success callback, and replace just a section of the currently-loaded page with the result.  My understanding is that MS's 'unobtrubsive javascript' may also help implement this, however I don't have any direct experience with it.

Obviously, all of this will only work if the browser has javascript enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm currently looking at AJAX to solve this problem because that sounds like a good solution to me. I don't have much experience with AJAX yet, so I'll have to figure it out a bit :) I will post here if I have any updates.