# MVC 4 Server-side validation not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario where I have a view with a partial that is loaded via `$.get`.  The partial has the following code:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CmaPartialModel                      
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{                   

   @Html.ValidationSummary()
   for(var i = 0; i < Model.DataItemsWithLabels.Count; i++)
   {                     
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataName,Model.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataValue,"data value error")

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataName,"data name error")
    }

<input type="submit" value="Save" />         
}
```

My controller action is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestPost(CmaPartialModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // code removed for quesiton
        }
        else 
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("E!", "Want to display this!");              
        }
        return PartialView("Transaction", model);                             
    }
```

Everything is working as expected in terms of client-side validation.

However, the errors that I have added in the controller are not displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have altered the controller action to inlcude: `ViewBag.Error = "error message";`

And the partioal view to include `@ViewBag.Error` - This is not upating either.  Is it perhaps an issue with AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thaks to Dean for his help.  Just wanted to make it clear that I was not using `Ajax.BeginForm` correctly.  My view should have looked like this:

```
<div id="form">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "form"   ))}
{
  // form stuff here
}
<div>
```

The form was not updating with anything - not just errors as I had no UpdateTargetId

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `AddModelError` is important here. It is used to determine what part of your model the error applies to.

You specified `E!` which, given it contains something that isn't a valid C# identifier, probably doesn't map to any part of your model!

If you want to add a general error then use `string.Empty` as the first parameter. You should find that it displays in your validation summary.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, no joy.  I have noticed that even if I set a ViewBag.Property in the controller method and try and display it, it doesn't show either. If I debug, the value is there but the form is not updating.  I'm wondering if it is an AJAX issue.

Comment: Can you check in Fiddler to see what is in the response? I'm wondering  whether the response is not replacing the content in your containing element when you do the POST? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908357/returning-data-to-a-partial-view

Comment: ,Thanks - you got me there.  The problem was simply that I had forgotten to specify the 'UpdateTargetId' in the Ajax Options.